# Change circle icon in Dialog

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog, progressdialog

I have a dialog with this code:

```
 progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);

    //-------------------------------------

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        progressDialog.setIndeterminateDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.custom_progress_background, getTheme()));
    }
    else{
        progressDialog.setIndeterminateDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.custom_progress_background));
    }

    //-------------------------------------
    progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
    progressDialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.MSG_SEARCH_DOING));
    progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
    progressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
    progressDialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, getString(R.string.cancel_msg), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            isStop = true;
            isCancel = true;
            showWaitingDialog();
        }
    });
    progressDialog.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {

        }
    });
    progressDialog.show();
```

and have output:
[image: Output dialog]

but I want my spinner like this:

[image: Required dialog]
anybody can help me do this without use third lib?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this line of code to change the progress icon 
`if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
progressDialog.setIndeterminateDrawable(getResources.getDrawable(R.drawable.custom_progress_drawable,getTheme()));
}else{
progressDialog.setIndeterminateDrawable(getResources.getDrawable(R.drawable.custom_progress_drawable));
}`
you will need atleast 4 images to make this custom_progress_drawable.xml, it can be created as under:

```
<animation-list>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/image1" android:duration="100" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/image2" android:duration="100" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/image3" android:duration="100" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/image4" android:duration="100" /></animation-list>
```

now set this drawable as your intermediate drawable in the progress dialog

Comment: But my min sdk only can is 9. this line code require min sdk is 21

Comment: many thanks, it work. But why it not rotate? How can i make this circle rotate?

Comment: Can u guide me how to make circle rotate? your line code can change icon of circle but it not rotate.

Comment: please paste your whole code to show the progress dialog.

Comment: the code seems alright, are you sure you are adding the rotate tag in your drawable xml??

Comment: I don't know how to add. I'm a newbie. Can u guide me?

Comment: the rotate property is determined by the drawable you use. now, did you use an image drawable or an xml drawable?

Comment: I used image drawable . :)

Comment: if you have used image drawable, it is going to be a little tricky for you, you have to create an animation using atleast 4 images. and the 4 images can be created by rotating your original image right and left. and at the end, set that animation xml as your intermediate drawable,hope it helps.

Comment: how can i create an animation using atleast 4 images?

Comment: how can I add this this drawable with 4 image?

Comment: what are you talking about?

Comment: u said " now set this drawable as your intermediate drawable in the progress dialog ". I don't understand how to do it. =.=

Comment: maybe I need a detail guide. :(

Comment: refer code again, and carefully. look for custome_animation_list.xml

Comment: I don't know how to say thanks with u. It work. Once again. Thanks you very much. :)

Answer (score 1):

Make one `xml` folder in res directory and put the `progressbar.xml` file in it .

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:pivotX="50%" android:pivotY="50%" android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:toDegrees="360">
    <shape android:shape="ring" android:innerRadiusRatio="3"
        android:thicknessRatio="8" android:useLevel="false">

        <size android:width="72dip" android:height="72dip" />
        <gradient android:type="sweep" android:useLevel="false"
            android:startColor="#448a29" 
            android:endColor="#447829"
            android:angle="0"
             />
    </shape>
</rotate>
```

Set startColor and endColor as per your choice .

Now set that `progress.xml` in ProgressBar's backgound .

Like this

```
<ProgressBar
 android:id="@+id/ProgressBar" 
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:background ="@xml/progressbar">
```

You used this sample and library `https://github.com/afollestad/material-dialogs`

Comment: can I change icon of circle of progressDialog ?

Comment: Yes , You can change icon and `progressDialog` circle color.

Comment: how can i do it without library? can you guide me detail?

Comment: You used this sample and library `https://github.com/afollestad/material-dialogs`

Comment: I can't see where is change icon of circle. :(

Answer (score 0):

You can make your progress dailog custom like this way,and this is exactle what you looking for

```
ACProgressFlower dialog = new ACProgressFlower.Builder(this)
                        .direction(ACProgressConstant.DIRECT_CLOCKWISE)
                        .themeColor(Color.WHITE)
                        .text("Title is here)
                        .fadeColor(Color.DKGRAY).build();
dialog.show();
```

for more see [this](https://github.com/Cloudist/ACProgressLite)